# Assigning text variables to numerical field in r

Tags: r, dataframe, text, dplyr, numeric

Hi everyone I am trying to assign categories to a range of values in a column that has a range of values from 365-433. I tried to use the case_when function and mimicked the syntax from the documentation as best I could but didn't seem to have the desired output. For clarification I am trying to designate data points with "Quadrant" values between 365-422 as "Transit", "Quadrant" values == to 424 as "ZOI", and "Quadrant" values == to 423 AND between 425-433 as "Adjacent". The last one is a bit tricky, because my focus is on that one 424 polygon, so if anyone has insight as to how I can account for that weird overlap in conditions I would so appreciate it.

Thanks!

```
sightingsData$quadID <- sightingsData$Quadrant
case_when(
  sightingsData$Quadrant %% 422 <= 0 ~ "Transit"
  sightingsData$Quadrant %% 424 == 0 ~ "ZOI"
  sightingsData$Quadrant %% 423 >= 0 ~ "Adjacent"
)
```

[image: As you can see, my above code just essentially copied the values from the pre-existing "Quadrant" field to the new field "quadID" that I created. Not sure why exactly, but my understanding of the case_when function is also a bit hazy]

Comment: Why are you using the modulus `%%` operator here? Don't you just want something like `case_when(sightingsData$Quadrant <= 422  ~ "Transit", sightingsData$Quadrant == 424 ~ "ZOI",  sightingsData$Quadrant >= 423  ~ "Adjacent")`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data aren't helpful because we can't copy/paste them into R for testing.

Comment: I'm not sure, I was really just following the syntax in the R help page. When I tried that it didn't work, and I got the same output, with these errors: Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
"case_when(
  sightingsData$Quadrant 422" and so on for my remaining arguments

Comment: I'd skip past the "fizz buzz" examples which do use modulus operators and instead look at the "star wars" examples to see perhaps more clear examples of how to use `case_when`. You just need to use value R expression that evaluates to a TRUE/FALSE value on the left side of the formula (`~`) and then the value you want on the right side.

Comment: Also, make sure to use `case_when` inside of a proper `mutate()` statement or be sure to save the results somewhere. Save it back to the data.frame after transformation rather than trying to change the class of the data afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is `between`, then we can change the code to

```
library(dplyr)
sightingsData <- sightingsData %>%
        mutate(quadID = case_when(Quadrant == 424 ~ "ZOI",
         Quadrant == 323 |between(Quadrant, 325, 433) ~ "Transit",

                   TRUE ~ "Adjacent"))
```

---

Also, for multiple groupings, an option is `cut`

```
sightingsData %>%
      mutate(quadID, cut(Quadrant, breaks = c(365, 422, 433, Inf), 
            labels = c("Transit", "ZOI", "Adjacent")))
```

Comment: Oh wow!! Thank you so so much! It's also now printing on the data table!

Comment: @SalmaAbdel-Raheem I did the `<-` assignment to your original data object.